# How to generate secring.gpg from pubring.kbx?

Tags: gnupg

I have a legacy software that works fine with older gnupg, however, we are attempting to update gnupg used. The older version of gnupg creates the secring.gpg, but this new version create pubring.kbx.
So, is there any way to create the secring.gpg from the pubring.kbx.
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The old keyring format was just a list of keyblocks, so use `gpg --export-secret-key KEYID` (binary, not ASCII-armored) to create such a file.

You need to have both `pubring.kbx` *and* `private-keys-v1.d` for this to work.

Comment: if you have only one key, you can omit the KEYID and it will work. Adding the destiantion file secring.gpg will make this work

Comment: Still looking for help on this, I am on the same road , I got the `pubring.kbx` but unable to get `secring.gpg` .